# Howto start a service at the beginning of the systemd boot sequence

Tags: systemd

How can I get a service started right at the beginning of the systemd boot sequence? shortly after the kernel has finished?

At the moment all my costum services get started at the end of systemd boot sequence. But i need one service which toggles some LEDs just then when systemd begins.

regards

Comment: Have you tried http://superuser.com/questions/544399/how-do-you-make-a-systemd-service-as-the-last-service-on-boot

Comment: How much "at the beginning"? `systemd` parallelizes everything, so it has no notion of "the beginning". You only can specify the exact dependencies against other units and it will generate the required ordering by itself.

Comment: my service just toggle some LEDs via a bash script to indicate that the system is still booting, so I assume there is no dependencies against other units. I don't specify after and before in the service file ist that right?